# Symfony2 - Access rights on external list of content

Tags: reporting-services, symfony, acl

New to symfony.

I'm designing a report portal. Reports are fetched from an external source (SSRS).

I get a tree of folders and reports from this source (this tree can change).

I need to give users the ability to assign roles access to certain nodes of this dynamic tree.

- Can I use ACL for this purpose ?
- I'm already using Sonata in my project, maybe I could use it to store the security.
- Could I be pointed to the right direction for implementing this dynamic external tree access right management interface ?

(Not asking for a full solution if there is no already existing, but SF2 components that I should use here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally stored the access rights to each nodes into the config file:

```
#app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    tree_access: 
        '/path/to/ssrs/node1': ['ROLE1']
        '/path/to/ssrs/node2': ['ROLE2', 'ROLE4']
        '/path/to/ssrs/node3': ['ROLE3']
```

And created a service which returns the report tree with resolved rights depending on the security_context.

Not sure it's the good way to go but since the community here seems so active...